# Select 1 row per hour

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2019.
I have a table in my database which contains a column called update_date.
For example, if I have the following data, I would like to import one data per hour within the last 24 hours.

```
2023-11-28 14:50:55
2023-11-28 15:10:33
2023-11-28 15:11:33
2023-11-28 15:53:33
2023-11-28 16:13:35
2023-11-28 16:56:49
2023-11-28 16:56:50
2023-11-29 00:37:02
2023-11-29 00:40:02
2023-11-29 00:41:02
2023-11-29 00:42:02
2023-11-29 00:44:02
```

I would like to return

```
2023-11-28 14:50:55
2023-11-28 15:10:33
2023-11-28 16:13:35
2023-11-29 00:37:02
```

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE update_date >= DATEADD(HOUR , -24, GETDATE())
```

I don't know how to add a query.
Please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using `GROUP BY` and `MIN()` :

```
SELECT MIN(update_date) as mints
FROM mytable
WHERE update_date >= DATEADD(HOUR , -24, GETDATE())
GROUP BY CAST(update_date as DATE), DATEPART(HOUR, update_date);
```

Comment: thx. i love u :-D!!

Comment: Glad to hear I could help :)